# End User Defined Tables on .Net Core

Tags: json, database, asp.net-core, dynamic

I have a web application that I developed with **.Net Core**. On the frontend, I will enable users to dynamically create tables and enter data.In the future, users can add new columns or delete columns. How should I create a structure in the database to store user data in the table in an application like this?
I think it as JSON, but would I have difficulty in the next column insertion and subtraction situations?
For example, the user will create a customer table and specify the columns as NAME, ADDRESS, PHONE. It will also fill in the data according to these columns. He can also add the MAIL column in the future. What should I do? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If they create tables and columns, why not handle it as tables and columns?

Comment: Can you explain a little more?